# Mongo Creating parent schema with empty array of children

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following post schema with an array of comments.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/huskysiberian1234/k8qpL2j9/)

```
var newPost = new Post({
            title: req.body.title,
            date: Date.now(),
            body: req.body.body,
            image: req.body.image,
            comments: {}
        })
        newPost.save(function(err){....)
```

I am trying to create a post, so add it to the database but with no comments yet. (Comments will be added later when user are going to comment). Tried null, {}, but nothing works :(

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out, I wanted to create a post with empty array of comments so all i had to do was:

```
var newPost = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        date: Date.now(),
        body: req.body.body,
        image: req.body.image,
        comments: []
    })
    newPost.save(function(err){....)
```